# Beamer: Section used before declaration

Tags: beamer, sectioning, listings

I'm creating a presentation using beamer and listings - when I end a section with a {lstlisting} call, the next section title appears in the slide. Is there a way that I can specify when the next section should come in?

Code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{CambridgeUS}
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{frame=tb,
  language=Java,
  aboveskip=3mm,
  belowskip=3mm,
  showstringspaces=false,
  columns=flexible,
  basicstyle={\fontsize{9}{9}\ttfamily},
  numbers=none,
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  tabsize=3
}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 

\usepackage{amsmath}

\title[The presentation]{The Presentation}

\begin{document}

\section[section 1]{section 1}

\begin{frame}
    This is the first section
\end{frame}

%%%%% Starts using 'Section 2' %%%%%

Hey! This is the wrong section!

\begin{lstlisting}[frame=single]

   public void hi(){
    system.out.println("Hello World!"); 
   }

\end{lstlisting}

%%%%%% Section 2 declared here %%%%%%

\section[section 2]{section 2}

\begin{frame}
  I should be the first with the title Section 2!
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Slides: (see section in top middle)
[image: First Slide]
[image: Second Slide]
[image: Third Slide]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The contents in your `lstlisting` environment need to be put within a `frame` environment.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{CambridgeUS}
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{frame=tb,
  language=Java,
  aboveskip=3mm,
  belowskip=3mm,
  showstringspaces=false,
  columns=flexible,
  basicstyle={\fontsize{9}{9}\ttfamily},
  numbers=none,
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  tabsize=3
}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 

\usepackage{amsmath}

\title[The presentation]{The Presentation}

\begin{document}

\section[section 1]{section 1}

\begin{frame}
    This is the first section
\end{frame}

%%%%% Starts using 'Section 2' %%%%%
\begin{frame}[fragile]
Hey! This is the correct section!

\begin{lstlisting}[frame=single]

   public void hi(){
    system.out.println("Hello World!"); 
   }

\end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}
%%%%%% Section 2 declared here %%%%%%

\section[section 2]{section 2}

\begin{frame}
  I should be the first with the title Section 2!
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: I tried using frame before, but it wouldn't compile -- the [fragile] tag is necessary!

Comment: @schil227: Yes, you're right. See [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/130131/18228) for an explanation.