# Latex document to beamer

Tags: beamer

Hello i want to make a beamer class from my tex document

I want to use the same code but there are occuring many problems with that.

First i have to get rid off

! You can't use `\unskip' in vertical mode.

My article class

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{mathtools,amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, positioning,automata, arrows.meta}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
  \pgfplotsset{%
       every tick label/.append style = {font=\tiny},
       every axis label/.append style = {font=\scriptsize}
     }

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\globalcolor}[1]{
  \color{#1}\global\let\default@color\current@color
}
\makeatother
\definecolor{Aufgabenfarbe}{RGB}{77,77,130}
\globalcolor{Aufgabenfarbe}
\KOMAoptions{%
    parskip=full,%
    fontsize=12pt}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true
    citecolor=Aufgabenfarbe,
}



\chapterfont{\color{Aufgabenfarbe}}  % sets colour of chapters


\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\hypersetup{linkcolor=Aufgabenfarbe}
\tableofcontents


\section{Aufgabe}
Sie haben dieses mit der Schreibmaschine und teilweise von Hand
gesetzte Dokument erhalten, über das auch schon der ein oder andere
Kaffee gelaufen ist. Leider hat niemand mehr das Original.\footnotemark Deswegen
ist es jetzt Ihre Aufgabe, das Dokument mit LaTeX und TikZ neu zu
setzen und eine dazu passende Präsentation mit Beamer zu setzen.

Bearbeiten Sie diese Aufgabe in Zweiergruppen. \underline{Ein} Student der
Zweiergruppe lädt im Moodle ein Zip-Archiv hoch, das \underline{ausschließlich}
die Dateien document.tex, literature.bib, presentation.tex und
studenten.txt enthält. Die Datei studenten.txt enthält die Namen und
Matrikelnummern beider Studenten der Zweiergruppe. Die TeX-Dateien
müssen mit folgendem Aufruf unter TeX Live 2019 fehlerfrei übersetzt
werden können: 
\footnotetext{Tatsächlich wurde auch dieses Dokument inklusive der Kaffeeflecken und handschriftlichen Skizzen mit LaTeX gesetzt.}
latexmk -pdf document.tex\\
latexmk -pdf presentation.tex

\subsection{Dokument}
Setzen Sie dieses Dokument mit LaTeX neu. Berücksichtigen Sie dabei die
Grundlagen guter typografischer Gestaltung und reproduzieren Sie \underline{alle
Inhalte und Strukturen} dieses Dokumentes, inklusive dieser
Aufgabenstellung.

\subsubsection{Hinweise}
\begin{itemize}
    \item[--]Setzen Sie Tabellen, Listen und Gliederungselemente mit den
    entsprechenden LaTeX-Befehlen.

    \item[--]Setzen Sie die Formeln mit dem Mathematikmodus von LaTeX neu. Verwenden
    Sie Theorem-Umgebungen, um Definitionen, Lemmata, Theoreme und Beweise
    zu setzen.

    \item[--]Setzen Sie Grafiken mit TikZ neu. Verwenden Sie Farbe, um semantisch
    unterschiedliche Elemente sinnvoll zu kennzeichnen.

     \item[--]Verwenden Sie LaTeX, um Gliederungselemente und Beschriftungen
    automatisch zu nummerieren.

    \item[--]Verwenden Sie BibTeX oder BibLaTeX, um das Literaturverzeichnis zu
    setzen.
\end{itemize}

\subsection{Präsentation}
Erstellen Sie mit LaTeX-Beamer eine Präsentation, die
alle Inhalte und Strukturen dieses Dokumentes enthält. Kürzen Sie die
Texte dabei so, dass gute Folien mit hilfreichen Stichpunkten
entstehen. Die Folien müssen alle Gliederungselemente, Tabellen,
Listen, Grafiken, Formeln, Definitionen, Lemmata, Theoreme und
Beweise dieses Dokumentes inklusive dieser Aufgabenstellung
enthalten. Auf das Literaturverzeichnis können Sie in der
Präsentation verzichten.

\section{Inhalte}
In diesem Abschnitt des Dokumentes finden Sie verschiedene
Inhaltselemente, deren Umsetzung mit LaTeX Sie im Rahmen der
Vorlesung kennen gelernt haben.
\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[%
        decision/.style={diamond,draw, text width=4.5em, text badly centered,
        inner sep=1pt},
        io/.style={trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110,
            minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, 
            draw=black,trapezium stretches=true},
        block/.style={minimum width=2cm,draw},
        forked/.style={to path={-| (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes}},
        node distance=1cm and 2cm]

        \node [io] (a){technical device};
        \node [below=of a,decision] (does) {Does it move?};
        \node [below right= of does,decision] (si) {Should it?}; 
        \node [below left = of does,decision] (si2) {Should it?};
        \node [below left=1cm and 1cm of si2,block] (wd40) {WD-40};
        \node [below right=1cm and 1cm of si,block] (dt) {duct tape};
        \path (wd40) -- node [block] (ok) {OK} (dt);
        \draw[-stealth,semithick]    (a) edge (does);
        \draw[-stealth,semithick,forked,nodes={above,font=\sffamily}]

        (does) edge node {yes}(si.north)
            (does) edge  node {no} (si2)
            (si2) edge node {yes}  (wd40)
            (si2) edge node {no}  (ok.160)
            (si) edge node {yes}  (ok.20)
            (si) edge node {no}  (dt);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Abbildung 1: Ablaufdiagramm der Ingenieurwissenschaft}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=Latex,shorten >=1pt,auto]
        \node[state] (s_0) at(2,0) {$s_0$};
        \node[state] (s_1) [above right=of s_0] {$s_1$};
        \node[state] (s_2) [below right=of s_1] {$s_2$};
        \node[state](s_3) [right=of s_2] {$s_3$};
        \node[state] (s_4) [above right=of s_3] {$s_4$};
        \node[] (correction) [below = of s_4] {};
        \node[state] (s_5) [below right= of correction] {$s_5$};
        \node[state](s_6) [right=of s_5] {$s_6$};
        \path[->] (s_1) edge node {0} (s_2)
        (s_3) edge node {0} (s_5);
        \path[->,dashed](s_6) edge[bend right=15] node [swap,pos=.3] {$last_3(w,1)=1$} (s_1);
        \draw (0,0)node[left]{2}--(s_0)--(s_2)--(s_3)--(13,0);
        \draw (0,0 |- s_1)node[left]{1}--(s_1)--(s_4)--(s_4-| 13,0);
        \draw (0,0 |- s_5)node[left]{3}--(s_5)--(s_6)--(s_6-| 13,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Ausführung w eines verteilten Systems. Der Zustand in
    Position 6 gehört zu Agent $A_3$. In diesem Zustand ist
    Position 1 die letzte Position von Agent $A_1$
    , die Agent
    $A_3$ kennt.}
\end{figure}

\subsection{Abbildungen und Tabellen}
Abbildungg 1 zeigt das Engineering Flow Chart. Es handelt sich um ein
Ablaufdiagramm, das einen Arbeitsablauf visualisiert. zeigt die
Ausführung eines verteilten Systems mit den Agenten 1, 2 und 3, während
verschiedene Sinus-Schwingungen zeigt.

Von den Abbildungen kommen wir nun zu einigen Tabellen. zeigt die
Verkaufspreise von Mücken, Gnus, Emus und Gürteltieren. Der tiefere Sinn
dieser Tabelle erschließt sich vermutlich nur dem Leser, der sie aus dem
LaTeX-Handbuch oder der Dokumentation des Pakets booktabs kennt. Dem
gegenüber zeigt die Synchronsprecher eines Filmes.

\begin{figure}[!h]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            width=16cm, height=5cm,
            xmin=0, xmax=10.2,
            ymin=-1.3, ymax=1.3,
            axis lines = left]

        \addplot [domain=0:9.2,samples=700,blue] {sin(deg(x))} node[right] {$\sin{(x)}$};
            \addplot [domain=0:9.2,samples=700,blue] {cos(deg(x))} node[right] {$\cos{(x)}$};
            \addplot [domain=0:9.2,samples=700,blue,dashed] {sin(deg(2*x))} node[right] {$\sin{(2x)}$};
            \addplot [domain=0:9.2,samples=700,blue,dashed] {cos(deg(2*x))} node[right] {$\cos{(2x)}$};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ p{3cm}p{3cm}p{3cm}  }
\hdashline
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{Artikel} \\
    \cdashline{1-2}
    Tiere& Beschreibungg &Preis \\
    \hdashline
    Mücke & pro Gramm  &13,65 \\
    ""&pro Stück& 0,01\\
    Gnu & ausgestopft & 92,50 \\
    Emu & ausgestopft& 33,33   \\ 
    Gülteltier & gefroren &8,99 \\ \hdashline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Übersicht über die Preise sehr verschiedener Tiere in
    unterschiedlichen Darreichungsformen.}
    \label{tab:template}
\end{table}

\clearpage
\begin{table}[!h]

\begin{tabular}[!h]{ p{5cm}p{5cm}p{5cm} }
\hdashline
Rolle& Stimme 1961/1962 &Stimme 1976/1977 \\
\hdashline
Lukas & Walter Schellmann  &Manfred Jenning \\
Jim Knopf&Elisabeth Göttlerr& 0,01\\
Gnu & ausgestopft & Winfried Küppers\\
Erzähler&Manfred Jenning&Sepp Wäsche\\
König Alfons&Max Bößl&Gerhard Jentsch\\
Herr Ärmel&Günter Knecht&Arno Bergler\\
Frau Waas&Rose Oehmichen&Rose Oehmichen\\ \hdashline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Synchronsprecher der Verfilmung von Jim Knopf und Lukas der
Lokomotivführer durch den Hessischen Rundfunk.}
\label{tab:template}
\end{table}

\clearpage

\subsection{Quellen}
Edsger Dijkstra war ein niederländischer Informatiker, der in seiner
Dissertation \cite{Dij59} eine Programmiersprache für die Electrologica X1
entwickelte. Die X1 war ein Digital-Computer, der in den 1950er Jahren
in den Niederlanden produziert wurde. Neben seiner Dissertation sei hier
noch auf ein nicht veröffentlichtes Paper \cite{Dij62} und ein Beitrag in einem
Sammelband \cite{Dij68} verwiesen.

Amir Pnueli war ein israelischer Informatiker, der wegweisende
Verdienste um die Einführung der temporalen Logik \cite{Pnu77} in die Informatik
geleistet hat.

Der IBM 701 war der erste für wissenschaftliche Zwecke bestimmte Rechner
von IBM. Sein Speedcoding System wird von John Backus im Journal-Artikel \cite{Bac45}
beschrieben. The C Programming Language \cite{Kr78} ist das erste Buch über die
Programmiersprache C.

\subsection{Quelltext}

Bubblesort ist ein Algorithmus, der vergleichsbasiert eine Liste von
Elementen sortiert:
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Java]
1 void bubblesrt(int array[]) {
2    int n = array.length;
3    int k;
4    for (int m = n; m >= 0; m--) {
5        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
6            k = i + 1;
7            if (array[i] > array[k]) {
8                swapNumbers(i, k, array);
9            }
10        }
11    }
12 }
\end{lstlisting}
\subsection{Theoreme und Mathematik}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\begin{lemma}(p-q-Forrmel.){
\label{lm1}
Mit F(x) = x+px+q gilt f($x_0$) = 0 genau dann,
wenn
 \[ x_0 = -\frac{p}{2} + \sqrt{\frac{p}{2}^{2}-q} \]\\
oder \[ x_0 = -\frac{p}{2} - \sqrt{\frac{p}{2}^{2}-q} \] }
\end{lemma}
\begin{proof}
  Die p-q-Formel ergibt sich aus 0 = x + px + q durch quadratische Ergänzung.
\end{proof}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\begin{definition}(Definition.){
Eine Definition ist die Bestimmung eines Begriffs}
\end{definition}

\begin{theorem}
  \label{th3}
f(x) = $x^{2}$ + 1 hat keine reelle Nullstelle.
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
Folgt unmittelbar mit Lemma \ref{lm1}.

Darüber hinaus gilt
\[ \sqrt{x^{4}} = x^{2}\].
\[(\frac{1}{x})^{2} = \frac{1}{x^{2}} und \]
\[lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n^{2}} = 0.\]
\end{proof}


\bibliographystyle{alphadin}
\bibliography{literature}

\end{document}
```

Want to create a presentation from that

First i want to show everything in that beamer class 
but that does not work...

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{mathtools,amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, positioning,automata, arrows.meta}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
  \pgfplotsset{%
       every tick label/.append style = {font=\tiny},
       every axis label/.append style = {font=\scriptsize}
     }

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\globalcolor}[1]{
  \color{#1}\global\let\default@color\current@color
}
\makeatother
\definecolor{Aufgabenfarbe}{RGB}{77,77,130}
\globalcolor{Aufgabenfarbe}
\title{Meine Präsentation}
\author{Martin Stuwe}
\usetheme{Luebeck}
\usecolortheme{crane}






\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents

\section{Aufgabe}
Sie haben dieses mit der Schreibmaschine und teilweise von Hand
gesetzte Dokument erhalten, über das auch schon der ein oder andere
Kaffee gelaufen ist. Leider hat niemand mehr das Original.\footnotemark Deswegen
ist es jetzt Ihre Aufgabe, das Dokument mit LaTeX und TikZ neu zu
setzen und eine dazu passende Präsentation mit Beamer zu setzen.

Bearbeiten Sie diese Aufgabe in Zweiergruppen. \underline{Ein} Student der
Zweiergruppe lädt im Moodle ein Zip-Archiv hoch, das \underline{ausschließlich}
die Dateien document.tex, literature.bib, presentation.tex und
studenten.txt enthält. Die Datei studenten.txt enthält die Namen und
Matrikelnummern beider Studenten der Zweiergruppe. Die TeX-Dateien
müssen mit folgendem Aufruf unter TeX Live 2019 fehlerfrei übersetzt
werden können: 
\footnotetext{Tatsächlich wurde auch dieses Dokument inklusive der Kaffeeflecken und handschriftlichen Skizzen mit LaTeX gesetzt.}
latexmk -pdf document.tex\\
latexmk -pdf presentation.tex

\subsection{Dokument}
Setzen Sie dieses Dokument mit LaTeX neu. Berücksichtigen Sie dabei die
Grundlagen guter typografischer Gestaltung und reproduzieren Sie \underline{alle
Inhalte und Strukturen} dieses Dokumentes, inklusive dieser
Aufgabenstellung.

\subsubsection{Hinweise}
\begin{itemize}
    \item[--]Setzen Sie Tabellen, Listen und Gliederungselemente mit den
    entsprechenden LaTeX-Befehlen.

    \item[--]Setzen Sie die Formeln mit dem Mathematikmodus von LaTeX neu. Verwenden
    Sie Theorem-Umgebungen, um Definitionen, Lemmata, Theoreme und Beweise
    zu setzen.

    \item[--]Setzen Sie Grafiken mit TikZ neu. Verwenden Sie Farbe, um semantisch
    unterschiedliche Elemente sinnvoll zu kennzeichnen.

     \item[--]Verwenden Sie LaTeX, um Gliederungselemente und Beschriftungen
    automatisch zu nummerieren.

    \item[--]Verwenden Sie BibTeX oder BibLaTeX, um das Literaturverzeichnis zu
    setzen.
\end{itemize}

\subsection{Präsentation}
Erstellen Sie mit LaTeX-Beamer eine Präsentation, die
alle Inhalte und Strukturen dieses Dokumentes enthält. Kürzen Sie die
Texte dabei so, dass gute Folien mit hilfreichen Stichpunkten
entstehen. Die Folien müssen alle Gliederungselemente, Tabellen,
Listen, Grafiken, Formeln, Definitionen, Lemmata, Theoreme und
Beweise dieses Dokumentes inklusive dieser Aufgabenstellung
enthalten. Auf das Literaturverzeichnis können Sie in der
Präsentation verzichten.

\section{Inhalte}
In diesem Abschnitt des Dokumentes finden Sie verschiedene
Inhaltselemente, deren Umsetzung mit LaTeX Sie im Rahmen der
Vorlesung kennen gelernt haben.
\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[%
        decision/.style={diamond,draw, text width=4.5em, text badly centered,
        inner sep=1pt},
        io/.style={trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110,
            minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, 
            draw=black,trapezium stretches=true},
        block/.style={minimum width=2cm,draw},
        forked/.style={to path={-| (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes}},
        node distance=1cm and 2cm]

        \node [io] (a){technical device};
        \node [below=of a,decision] (does) {Does it move?};
        \node [below right= of does,decision] (si) {Should it?}; 
        \node [below left = of does,decision] (si2) {Should it?};
        \node [below left=1cm and 1cm of si2,block] (wd40) {WD-40};
        \node [below right=1cm and 1cm of si,block] (dt) {duct tape};
        \path (wd40) -- node [block] (ok) {OK} (dt);
        \draw[-stealth,semithick]    (a) edge (does);
        \draw[-stealth,semithick,forked,nodes={above,font=\sffamily}]

        (does) edge node {yes}(si.north)
            (does) edge  node {no} (si2)
            (si2) edge node {yes}  (wd40)
            (si2) edge node {no}  (ok.160)
            (si) edge node {yes}  (ok.20)
            (si) edge node {no}  (dt);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Abbildung 1: Ablaufdiagramm der Ingenieurwissenschaft}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=Latex,shorten >=1pt,auto]
        \node[state] (s_0) at(2,0) {$s_0$};
        \node[state] (s_1) [above right=of s_0] {$s_1$};
        \node[state] (s_2) [below right=of s_1] {$s_2$};
        \node[state](s_3) [right=of s_2] {$s_3$};
        \node[state] (s_4) [above right=of s_3] {$s_4$};
        \node[] (correction) [below = of s_4] {};
        \node[state] (s_5) [below right= of correction] {$s_5$};
        \node[state](s_6) [right=of s_5] {$s_6$};
        \path[->] (s_1) edge node {0} (s_2)
        (s_3) edge node {0} (s_5);
        \path[->,dashed](s_6) edge[bend right=15] node [swap,pos=.3] {$last_3(w,1)=1$} (s_1);
        \draw (0,0)node[left]{2}--(s_0)--(s_2)--(s_3)--(13,0);
        \draw (0,0 |- s_1)node[left]{1}--(s_1)--(s_4)--(s_4-| 13,0);
        \draw (0,0 |- s_5)node[left]{3}--(s_5)--(s_6)--(s_6-| 13,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Ausführung w eines verteilten Systems. Der Zustand in
    Position 6 gehört zu Agent $A_3$. In diesem Zustand ist
    Position 1 die letzte Position von Agent $A_1$
    , die Agent
    $A_3$ kennt.}
\end{figure}

\subsection{Abbildungen und Tabellen}
Abbildungg 1 zeigt das Engineering Flow Chart. Es handelt sich um ein
Ablaufdiagramm, das einen Arbeitsablauf visualisiert. zeigt die
Ausführung eines verteilten Systems mit den Agenten 1, 2 und 3, während
verschiedene Sinus-Schwingungen zeigt.

Von den Abbildungen kommen wir nun zu einigen Tabellen. zeigt die
Verkaufspreise von Mücken, Gnus, Emus und Gürteltieren. Der tiefere Sinn
dieser Tabelle erschließt sich vermutlich nur dem Leser, der sie aus dem
LaTeX-Handbuch oder der Dokumentation des Pakets booktabs kennt. Dem
gegenüber zeigt die Synchronsprecher eines Filmes.

\begin{figure}[!h]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            width=16cm, height=5cm,
            xmin=0, xmax=10.2,
            ymin=-1.3, ymax=1.3,
            axis lines = left]

        \addplot [domain=0:9.2,samples=700,blue] {sin(deg(x))} node[right] {$\sin{(x)}$};
            \addplot [domain=0:9.2,samples=700,blue] {cos(deg(x))} node[right] {$\cos{(x)}$};
            \addplot [domain=0:9.2,samples=700,blue,dashed] {sin(deg(2*x))} node[right] {$\sin{(2x)}$};
            \addplot [domain=0:9.2,samples=700,blue,dashed] {cos(deg(2*x))} node[right] {$\cos{(2x)}$};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ p{3cm}p{3cm}p{3cm}  }
\hdashline
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{Artikel} \\
    \cdashline{1-2}
    Tiere& Beschreibungg &Preis \\
    \hdashline
    Mücke & pro Gramm  &13,65 \\
    ""&pro Stück& 0,01\\
    Gnu & ausgestopft & 92,50 \\
    Emu & ausgestopft& 33,33   \\ 
    Gülteltier & gefroren &8,99 \\ \hdashline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Übersicht über die Preise sehr verschiedener Tiere in
    unterschiedlichen Darreichungsformen.}
    \label{tab:template}
\end{table}

\clearpage
\begin{table}[!h]

\begin{tabular}[!h]{ p{5cm}p{5cm}p{5cm} }
\hdashline
Rolle& Stimme 1961/1962 &Stimme 1976/1977 \\
\hdashline
Lukas & Walter Schellmann  &Manfred Jenning \\
Jim Knopf&Elisabeth Göttlerr& 0,01\\
Gnu & ausgestopft & Winfried Küppers\\
Erzähler&Manfred Jenning&Sepp Wäsche\\
König Alfons&Max Bößl&Gerhard Jentsch\\
Herr Ärmel&Günter Knecht&Arno Bergler\\
Frau Waas&Rose Oehmichen&Rose Oehmichen\\ \hdashline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Synchronsprecher der Verfilmung von Jim Knopf und Lukas der
Lokomotivführer durch den Hessischen Rundfunk.}
\label{tab:template}
\end{table}

\clearpage

\subsection{Quellen}
Edsger Dijkstra war ein niederländischer Informatiker, der in seiner
Dissertation \cite{Dij59} eine Programmiersprache für die Electrologica X1
entwickelte. Die X1 war ein Digital-Computer, der in den 1950er Jahren
in den Niederlanden produziert wurde. Neben seiner Dissertation sei hier
noch auf ein nicht veröffentlichtes Paper \cite{Dij62} und ein Beitrag in einem
Sammelband \cite{Dij68} verwiesen.

Amir Pnueli war ein israelischer Informatiker, der wegweisende
Verdienste um die Einführung der temporalen Logik \cite{Pnu77} in die Informatik
geleistet hat.

Der IBM 701 war der erste für wissenschaftliche Zwecke bestimmte Rechner
von IBM. Sein Speedcoding System wird von John Backus im Journal-Artikel \cite{Bac45}
beschrieben. The C Programming Language \cite{Kr78} ist das erste Buch über die
Programmiersprache C.

\subsection{Quelltext}

Bubblesort ist ein Algorithmus, der vergleichsbasiert eine Liste von
Elementen sortiert:
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Java]
1 void bubblesrt(int array[]) {
2    int n = array.length;
3    int k;
4    for (int m = n; m >= 0; m--) {
5        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
6            k = i + 1;
7            if (array[i] > array[k]) {
8                swapNumbers(i, k, array);
9            }
10        }
11    }
12 }
\end{lstlisting}
\subsection{Theoreme und Mathematik}

\begin{lemma}(p-q-Forrmel.){
\label{lm1}
Mit F(x) = x+px+q gilt f($x_0$) = 0 genau dann,
wenn
 \[ x_0 = -\frac{p}{2} + \sqrt{\frac{p}{2}^{2}-q} \]\\
oder \[ x_0 = -\frac{p}{2} - \sqrt{\frac{p}{2}^{2}-q} \] }
\end{lemma}
\begin{proof}
Die p-q-Formel ergibt sich aus 0 = x + px + q durch quadratische Ergänzung.
\end{proof}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\begin{definition}(Definition.){
Eine Definition ist die Bestimmung eines Begriffs}
\end{definition}

\begin{theorem}
  \label{th3}
f(x) = $x^{2}$ + 1 hat keine reelle Nullstelle.
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
Folgt unmittelbar mit Lemma \ref{lm1}.

Darüber hinaus gilt
\[ \sqrt{x^{4}} = x^{2}\].
\[(\frac{1}{x})^{2} = \frac{1}{x^{2}} und \]
\[lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n^{2}} = 0.\]
\end{proof}


\bibliographystyle{alphadin}
\bibliography{literature}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please clarify your question regarding " make a beamer class". Do you want to create a beamer presentation from the shown article code? Please also show what you tried so far to make a beamer presentation.

Comment: Please also comment on "Erstellen Sie mit LaTeX-Beamer eine Präsentation, die
alle Inhalte und Strukturen dieses Dokumentes enthält." (from line 96 of your example document, roughly translated to "Create a latex beamer based presentation containing the contents and the strcucture of the current document.") Currently, your question seems like a do-it-for-me type of question which somehow seems to aim at solving the quoted assignment. Therefore, please show what you tried so far, what did not work as well as corensponding small examples.

Comment: I just want to show it in beamer but i get one error after another..

Comment: Contents in `beamer` have to be assigned to `frames`. These are completely missing in your example.  Maybe you should have a look at a basic introduction into beamer such as https://de.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Beamer_Presentations:_A_Tutorial_for_Beginners_(Part_1)%E2%80%94Getting_Started

Comment: i've done it now but get listing error

Comment: [10] (D:\Latex\tex/latex/listings\lstlang1.sty)
Runaway argument?
{\subsection {Quelltext} 
! Paragraph ended before \lst@next was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.286 \end{frame}

Comment: Have a look at the `fragile` option. [Can't insert code in my beamer slide](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/130109/134144)  might alos be helpful.

Comment: Thanks mate you've saved my life

Comment: One more how do i scale figures right so they are not outside the frame?

Comment: Sorry for sounding a bit harsh, but I'm not here to do your homework for you nor are the comments to a question intended for a discussion about an only vaguely related topic. You might want to use the search function on this site or a search engine of your choice to find more information on how to scale images. A simple google search reveals this, that might also be suited for your case: [Scaling a tikzpicture for a Beamer slide](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/62788/134144)

Comment: If your problem persists, ask a new question woth a well prepared [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and a description of your problem.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is possible **at some extent** and compile it, just replacing  the line 40 to by:

`\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks,fragile]`

But the result is still, of course, is a bunch of incomplete crap. The answer of this site are not to revise long codes but to clarify *one* specific problem in a code as short as possible (but compilable).

Nonetheless, to obtain a decent result, here are some suggestions to start:

- Make several empty frames, not only one breakable. Then add manually reasonable small contents of the old document to each frame, and revise that contents, in special:
- Sections and subsection headers **must** be between frames not within frames.
- Some commands as \clearpage will have not any sense in a presentation.
- Figures and tables can be in floats in beamer, but have no sense use float options, and in fact have no sense use floats at all, except to show the captions, which in turn, are usually expendable in a presentation.
- Figures and tables could not will fit well from A4 format to beamer dimensions directly, unless you use always relative lengths (e.g.: `.5\textwidth`)  instead absolute lengths (e.g.: 7cm), and even then, you probably you will need fix also font sizes.